# R combinations, looking for faster and more efficient way(package,code,parallel cpu) than basic R

Tags: r, performance, matrix, combinations

I'm using basic R for combinations.

For example, let's say I have a matrix with 2 rows and 5 columns:

```
 z<-matrix(c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1),nrow=2,ncol=5,byrow = TRUE)

[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]

[1,]    1    2    1    3    2

[2,]    2    1    3    2    1
```

I'm using the code below for combinations of sets of 3 from the 5 columns:

```
l<- apply(X = combn(seq_len(ncol(z)), 3),MAR = 2,FUN = function(jj) {apply(z[, jj], 1, paste, collapse="") })
```

This exports what I need:

```
[,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]  [,10]

[1,] "121" "123" "122" "113" "112" "132" "213" "212" "232" "132"

[2,] "213" "212" "211" "232" "231" "221" "132" "131" "121" "321"
```

The problem starts when I'm using big data in a matrix,
for example when I have a matrix with 15000 rows and 17 columns and I need the combinations of sets of 10 from the 17 columns.

In this example this export takes very long time.

Is there any faster and more efficient way than basic R (maybe some packages or code,or using parallel cpu's) for this example of combinations?

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, FX 8320, 16GB RAM.

Comment: Don't know how much time you can save, but you can simplify a little your code: `apply(z,1,function(x) combn(x,3,FUN=paste,collapse=""))` will produce `t(l)`.

Comment: I have a feeling we'll see Dirk come by and recommend [`Rcpp`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rcpp). :) That might be a decent option to explore if you haven't already.

Comment: For your example you're looking to generate 292 million combinations (17 choose 10 times 15000), so it shouldn't be too surprising that it takes a while...

Comment: @nicola I would suggest adding that as an answer with some benchmarking -- I found with a 100 x 17 matrix selecting n columns that your code ran in 0.3 seconds versus 16 seconds for the OP's code.

Comment: when I've worked with generating combinations I've noticed that `paste` function slows the code. keeping data in matrix form makes the code run much more efficient

Comment: Thank you all for the replies .@nicola i just test your simplest code  but unfortunately i did not save time .Thanks for your try .

Comment: @josilber i know the number of combinations and i m not surprising for that it takes a while. i only ask if there is a way or code faster than mine .

Comment: @josliber, when you tested nicola’s code, did you select the same number of columns? When I tested them, I didn’t see that much improvement. Maybe I’m doing something wrong.

Comment: @JosephWood not sure; sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @inscaven points out, the real time crunch comes from `paste`. If we simply had to generate all 17 choose 10 combinations 15000 times, that wouldn't take that long with the advent of a couple of highly optimized packages in `R`, `arrangements` and `RcppAlgos` (I am the author):

```
set.seed(101)
testMat <- matrix(sample(1000, 15000 * 17, TRUE), nrow = 15000)

library(arrangements)
system.time(lapply(1:15000, function(x) {
    temp <- combinations(x = testMat[x, ], k = 10)
    x
}))
  user  system elapsed 
 6.879   2.133   9.014

library(RcppAlgos)
system.time(lapply(1:15000, function(x) {
    temp <- comboGeneral(testMat[x, ], 10)
    x
}))
  user  system elapsed 
 5.770   2.178   7.953
```

Compared to `combn` loaded in `base R`:

```
system.time(lapply(1:15000, function(x) {
    temp <- combn(testMat[x, ], 10)
    x
}))
    user  system elapsed 
 261.163   1.093 262.608
```

If we must combine our results into a matrix of characters, there isn't much more in `base R` that we can do. Even if we use either of the optimized libraries mentioned above, we are still left looping over all rows and pasting the results which is slow.

```
system.time(t1 <- lapply(1:50, function(x) {
    combn(testMat[x, ], 10, paste0, collapse = "")
}))
  user  system elapsed 
 6.847   0.070   6.933

## from package arrangements
system.time(t2 <- lapply(1:50, function(x) {
    apply(combinations(x = testMat[x, ], k = 10), 1, paste0, collapse = "")
}))
  user  system elapsed 
 6.318   0.032   6.353
```

This isn't really a win. We need a new approach.

***Enter `Rcpp`***

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector pasteCombos(int n, int r, CharacterVector v, int numRows) {

    int r1 = r - 1, r2 = r - 2;
    int numIter, count = 0;
    CharacterVector comboVec = Rcpp::no_init_vector(numRows);

    std::vector<int> z(r);
    std::iota(z.begin(), z.end(), 0);

    while (count < numRows) {
        numIter = n - z[r1];
        if ((numIter + count) > numRows)
            numIter = numRows - count;

        for (int i = 0; i < numIter; ++i, ++count, ++z[r1])
            for (int k = 0; k < r; ++k)
                comboVec[count] += v[z[k]];

        for (int i = r2; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (z[i] != (n - r + i)) {
                ++z[i];
                for (int k = (i + 1); k < r; ++k) 
                    z[k] = z[k - 1] + 1;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return comboVec;
}
```

This function simply generates all combinations of `v` choose `r` and paste the results on the fly via `+=`. This generates a vector without the necessity of dealing with rows of a matrix. Let's see if we have any improvements.

```
numCombs <- choose(17, 10)
charMat <- matrix(as.character(testMat), nrow = 15000)

funOP <- function(z, r) {
    apply(X = combn(seq_len(ncol(z)), r), MAR = 2,FUN = function(jj) {apply(z[, jj], 1, paste, collapse="") })
}

system.time(t1 <- funOP(testMat[1:100, ], 10))
   user  system elapsed 
 22.221   0.110  22.330 

system.time(t2 <- lapply(1:100, function(x) {
     pasteCombos(17, 10, charMat[x,], numCombs)
}))
  user  system elapsed 
 7.890   0.085   7.975
```

Nearly 3 times faster... not bad, but we can do better.

***Enter `parallel`***

```
library(parallel)
system.time(t3 <- mclapply(1:100, function(x) {
    pasteCombos(17, 10, charMat[x,], numCombs)
}, mc.cores = 8)) ## you will have to adjust this on your computer.. I'm running MacOS with 8 cores
  user  system elapsed 
 1.430   0.454   1.912
```

Now we are talking!!! Nearly 12 times faster!!

Here is a sanity check:

```
all.equal(t1, do.call(rbind, t2))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(t1, do.call(rbind, t3))
# [1] TRUE
```

In total, if we assume we can complete 100 rows in 2 seconds, we can complete our task in a respectable `2 * 150 = 300 seconds = 5 minutes`.